# Parsley: Unable to execute command line tool after building it.. "Error while loading shared libraries: libparsley.so.0"

Tags: ubuntu, shared-libraries, parsley

I'm getting started with Parsley (parslets.com), an interesting tool to parse data out of webpages.

http://parselets.com/dev/command_line

I've downloaded the source, built it, and now I'm unable to run it:

```
parsley: error while loading shared libraries: libparsley.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm a bit of a *nix newbie, so I'm stuck on this.. here is what I did:

1. I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 64bit
2. I downloaded the source
3. I ran "sudo ./configure" and installed dependencies (using apt-get) as necessary
4. I ran "make install"
5. I attempted to run parsley by typing "parsley"

Any ideas? thanks.

- Alex

Comment: I'd like to answer this but I'll struggle it and suggest to migrate to superuser instead--if it can be done.

Comment: migrating it sounds fine if thats the best place for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have gone away, or at least I can't say I did anything to fix it but it no longer happens. My only guess (grasping at straws) is that when I installed the suggested updates for Ubuntu yesterday something changed or got fixed that affected this.

Update: It turns out, I needed to run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

What must have happened is updating my system ran that for me.

Comment: I've just encountered this problem and this worked for me (Ubuntu 10.10 x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

It appear that this file must be compiled from the source that you have
You should type 'make' first before 'sudo make install'
It will compile the parsley.c file to parsley.so.0

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck. I typed 'make' and it essentially said nothing to do.  Make install did in fact build it, there is a libparsley.so.0 in .libs, which looks like a symbolic link to libparsley.so.0.0.0 which exists.

Comment: Any chance this is a 32bit/64bit issue?

Answer (score 0):

What does `"ldd parsley"` say? Chances are `ldd` doesn't find `libparsley.so.0` either.

If so, the problem is that `"make install"` didn't install `libparsley.so.0` into the right place. Find that right place, and move libparsley.so.0 (as well as `libparsley.so.0.0.0`) there (I believe on 64-bit Ubuntu `/usr/lib32` is the right place if `libparsley.so.0.0.0` is a 32-bit library, and `/usr/lib` (or `/usr/lib64`) if it is a 64-bit library).

Comment: The problem seems to have resolved itself, bizarre. I had another problem resolve itself yesterday too... I did install the suggested updates on Ubuntu yesterday, maybe something broken got fixed?